# Does exterior wall cladding have much impact on sound or temperature transmission?

Tags: insulation, brick, siding, sound-proofing, temperature

I'm buying a new house which is all brick except of back side. Master's bedroom is going to have 1 siding wall and 1 brick wall. I can select an option to add brick on the back wall for additional $6k.

Anybody had experience with full brick house vs 3/4 of brick? is there gonna be a noticeable difference in sound / temperature isolation? I live in Texas, so it's quite hot during summer, like 100-110 Fahrenheit. Sound - I mean traffic noise, neighbors etc.

Comment: For the tiny percentage of overall cost, I'd brick the whole house just because I think it looks better. But that's my opinion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my experience, most traffic noise comes through windows. Even when they're modern and closed they let in much more sound than even a basic framed, insulated wall. Unless you have no windows in the room you probably wouldn't notice much benefit. Fiber cement siding is already fairly heavy and dense.

Masonry is a double-edged sword when it comes to energy efficiency. It'll repel the sun for a while, but it'll also absorb huge amounts of heat during the day and keep it radiating at your room at night. Whether that's good or bad depends on sun exposure, etc. I'm also in a frequently hot climate and I don't think I've ever heard anyone suggest a brick wall as a mitigation technique. Insulation quality is more important.

Comment: I lived in Israel for a short while. Almost every structure was made of poured concrete. It did a fine job of keeping the interior cool (especially with small windows that were shaded) during the day, while absorbing the heat of the sun. At night, that heat radiated inside keeping it warm inside at night. Mind you, these were bare concrete walls (no paint on the exterior, and I don't recall any on the interior, either) and I'm not sure if there was _any_ insulation between interior & exterior.

Comment: Thing is, Texas is probably not cool at night during the summer, so lingering heat is a concern.

Comment: True. Israel is a desert and can get _quite_ cold at night. Texas is... well... Texas... :) Just adding support to your comments on the heat properties of masonry walls.